# Python: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x

starting with python and I already failed miserably...
Started with a clean install for Python 3.9.5
Now, executing a simple "HelloWorld" by using "py test.py" works just fine, but whenever i try to import something like Redditor or Submission it returns "ModuleNotFoundError" (ofc after installing the module, tried pip3 install Redditor, pip install Redditor etc). Tried to modify my PATH variables but nothing seems to help. Can someone walk me step by step with setting this up? I'm very new to this. I tried different approaches but nothing seems to work.
Also for some reason I dont have problems with "praw", installed it and no error.

Comment: Have you tried; `import reddit` and `import submission`. Because you install them by `pip install Reddit` and `pip install Submission`, but you have to import with lowercase. Can this be the problem?

Comment: If the problem is not as I described above, please share your code.

Comment: That's not how you install a package. Both `Redditor` and `Submission` are classes (or [models](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/praw_models.html)) inside the PRAW package, so you must do `pip install praw` as seen [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation.html#installing-praw).

Comment: Dear God, you're a genius! Why haven't I thought about it... It works now, thank you!
Edit: I cannot upvote your post m.i.cosacak since I just registered, but thank you so much for helping again.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! [Following the guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294792/9997212) I can post an answer so you can mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Redditor` and `Submission` are classes inside the PRAW package, so you cannot install them directly using `pip install Redditor`, for example.

[According to the package](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation.html#installing-praw), you can install it using `pip install praw`.